# Excel VBA - Can I change the font of a single item inside the combobox list?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a combobox that contains a long list of fitness exercises. As there are many exercises, to avoid confusion I have sorted them by muscle group as you scroll down. What I would like to do now is change the font or background color of the item that contains the category name, for example:

This is what my combobox list looks like

[image]

This is how I'd like it to look: bold text only for this example, but I'd like to be able to change the color, size and background.
**...Legs...**
Squats
Leg Press
Leg extensions

**...Chest...**
BenchPress
Chestpress
Etc...

This is the code of my combobox

```
'COMBOBOX1
Private Sub exercise_Change()
    Dim f As Range
    
    ActiveCell.Value = exercise.Value

    If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then
        Set f = Sheets("database").Columns("A:K").Find(ActiveCell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            If f.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add ActiveCell, f.Hyperlinks(1).Address
        End If
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider using a combo box that contains your muscle groups, and below that a simple list box that is populated when a selection is made on the combo box, with the appropriate exercise.  Much more complicated, but I am pretty sure there is no simple way to enhance the font on a combo box.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I actually already have another combobox that categorically encompasses the exercises.

So combobox 1 = Press Pattern, Combobox 2 = all press exercises (including legs and arms shuffle).

But thinking in this sense I could include a third combobox to divide the muscle groups.